# Are OpenMPI and MPICH2 compatible?

Tags: mpi, compatibility, openmpi, mpich

I'm using OS X and Bash. I am trying to run a program across two systems, and the host has OpenMPI 1.6.4 and the other node has MPICH2. I am running into problems, and this is my first time using any kind of MPI implementation, so I don't know if I am just doing it wrong, or it is impossible/a lot more difficult to get it to run when they are using different MPI software.

Thanks for any insight you guys have.

Comment: This will work as well as x86 binaries will on ARM :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install the SAME MPI implementation and version on ALL systems where the job will run.  Mixing implementations in a single job in the manner described it not supported.